# What's the best OOP pattern to do this in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The code snippet would not compile as it only meant to showcase what I would like to achieve:
Say I have an Interface:

```
      public Interface IWalker 
      {
          //Compiles but not what I need
          double DistanceTravelled {get; set;}

          //Compiler error - cant be private for set, but that's what I need
          //double DistanceTravelled {get; private set;}
      }

      public abstract AbstractWalker : IWalker 
      {
           //Error:Cannot implement - but thats what I need
           //protected double DistanceTravelled {get; private set} 

           //Error the set is not public and I dont want the property to be public
           //public double DistanceTravelled { get;private  set; }

             //Compiles but not what i need at all since I want a protected 
             // property -a. and have it behave as readonly - b. but 
             // need it to be a part of the interface -c.
             public double DistanceTravlled {get; set;}

      }
```

All of my concrete instances of AbstractWalker are actually type of IWalker. 
What would be the best way to achieve the design I have specified in the snippet?

Comment: Is there some reason it needs to be an interface? Abstract classes are basically the same thing, except you can add protected methods.

Comment: found this, maybe it helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420133/do-adding-properties-to-an-interface-prevent-creating-private-protected-set-in/2420147#2420147

Comment: @Mike, yes, so I have a choice to program against either one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want private set, just specify a get in the interface:

```
  public interface IWalker 
  {
      double DistanceTravelled {get; }
  }
```

the implementer of IWalker can then specify private set:

```
  public class Walker : IWalker 
  {
      public double DistanceTravelled { get; private set;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your design. An interface is used to describe the 'public contract' of your API, so it's very strange that you want (a) a private setter and (b) a protected implementation.

- The private setter at the interface level does not make any sense (see Mark Heaths answer if you want a property with only a getter on the interface)
- The protected implementation is also weird, since by implementing the interface the property is public anyway.

You will have to provide more information about your design if you need more help.