# Implement a property with a private set

Tags: c#, class, interface

How do I implement a interface with a property that has a private set eg:

```
public interface IExample{
      int Test{private set;get;}
}

public class Example : IExample{
      private int _test;
      public int Test{
            private set{
               _test=value;
            }
            get{
               return _test;
            }
      }
}
```

I understand why it will not compile as access modifiers are not allowed in the interface but {set;get;} does not work either.

I have tried a few other ways with no success but the above example best describes the problem.

Comment: `but {set;get;} does not work either.` - really? You have to do `set` instead of `private set` in `class` too.

Comment: {set;get;} does work in the interface but will not allow me to use private set in its implementation.

Comment: `{get;}` in the interface, `{get; private set;}` in the object implementing it, as [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2420147/3155705).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to ensure that nobody calls the setter on your property. You can do that by simply omitting it from the public interface:

```
public interface IExample{
      int Test{get;}
}

public class Example : IExample{
      private int _test;
      public int Test{
            private set{
               _test=value;
            }
            get{
               return _test;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand why it will not compile as access modifiers are not allowed in the interface

Correct.

An `interface` cannot be messed with. When implementing an `interface`.. you *must* adhere to the contract it has put before you.

That means you must have a `public` getter and setter if you have specified as such in your `interface` definition. That is the idea - an `interface` represents a *public contract* for the type implementing it.

Omit it from the interface and you are free to put whatever else you want on the implementing type.